# How to set up Custom Fields in the Product Variations interface for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The WordPress plugin WooCommerce supports [Custom Fields](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/custom-fields/).

Custom Fields can be toggled under Screen Options:

[image]

[image]

However, these Custom Fields do no get segregated for [product variations](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/).  There is only one set of Custom Fields that applies to all product variations in the WooCommerce interface, and this is inappropriate because different product variations may have different product MPNs, for example, which is one of the Custom Fields I have set up for myself.

The [closest off-site solution](https://damartrianggoro.com/web-application/adding-custom-fields-woocommerce-product-variation/) I found does not link up to custom fields.  The code, shown below, shows how one can set up input fields in the Product Variations interface.  How can I modify the solution below to link up the Product Variations interface the custom fields?

This question is distinct from questions concerned with Advanced Custom Fields, as I am not using that plugin.  Furthermore, at least [one other similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009220/woocommerce-add-custom-fields-to-product-variations) but I'm not proficient with PHP and I don't comprehend it, nor do I know if it is relevant - but I will point out that solution has not been accepted by the OP and I don't want to necropost there.

```
/** 
 * Create new fields for variations
 *
 */
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_ean_code[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'EAN-CODE', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'EAN-CODE',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter your custom EAN code.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_ean_code', true )
        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_stock_amsterdam[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'Nr. of Stock in Amsterdam', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter nr. of Stock in Amsterdam', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_stock_amsterdam', true ),
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                            'step'  => 'any',
                            'min'   => '0'
                        ) 
        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_stock_den_bosch[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'Nr. of Stock in Den Bosch', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter nr. of Stock in Den Bosch', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_stock_den_bosch', true ),
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                            'step'  => 'any',
                            'min'   => '0'
                        ) 
        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_stock_alkmaar[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'Nr. of Stock in Alkmaar', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter nr. of Stock in Alkmaar', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_stock_alkmaar', true ),
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                            'step'  => 'any',
                            'min'   => '0'
                        ) 
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
 */
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {

    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_ean_code'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ean_code', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
    $number_field = $_POST['_stock_amsterdam'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_amsterdam', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
    }
    $number_field = $_POST['_stock_den_bosch'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_den_bosch', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
    }
    $number_field = $_POST['_stock_alkmaar'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_alkmaar', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
    }

}

// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );


// Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec so what solution do you use, may I ask, for custom fields like MPN for multiple product variations?

Comment: It's just the **M**anufacturer **P**art **N**umber for the product - like a barcode or an ID number.  But it is different for each product variation.

Comment: So [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700927/display-and-save-a-custom-field-in-product-variations-options-edit-page/43701470#43701470) could do the trick or [**search answers** that have this hook: `woocommerce_save_product_variation`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_save_product_variation)